# Get Current Custom Taxonomy ID by Post ID

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, terms

If I know the current post id that i have in the variable $pid

I use `$terms = get_the_terms($pid, 'custom_category');`

How do I get just the `term id/term_taxonomy_id`

if I `var_dump` `$terms` I see what I want...but I have no idea how the heck to return just the id, not an array, just the id.

Bare in mind...I less than 1/2 know what I'm doing...just face rolling keyboard to get what I want...but learning more everyday.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Probably better to use `get_the_terms`).

```
$terms =  wp_get_object_terms( $pid, 'custom_category', array('fields'=>'ids'));
```

Get an array of term ids (will always been array, even if it is an array of one):

```
$ids = wp_list_pluck( $terms, 'term_id' );
```

If you just want one id... then 'pop' out the last id:

```
 $id = array_pop($ids);
```

See also PHP docs on `array_pop` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php)

Comment: appreciate the answer...but that still just returns an array that I don't know how to get the id out of...I'm very much a rookie...no idea what to do with the return.

Comment: @BrianThornton have edited my answer....

Comment: getting there...but it's late and I can barely see...will pick up again tomorrow...thanks for the help.

Comment: @BrianThornton - you will always have an array because posts can have more than one term associated with them. You'll have to take out the ID youself. I would use `get_the_terms` rather than `wp_get_object_terms`.

Comment: So this answered my question....the basics are going to be the death of me.  I'm still not able to get what I want/need to work...but it's involved.  So I'm writing up a rather lengthy question that I will post in a little while.  Thanks guys...I learn more every day here!

Answer (score -1):

try this code for getting category id from post id.

```
$categories = get_the_category( $post_id );
```

Comment: Except for the fact that from http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category "This function only returns results from the default "category" taxonomy. For custom taxonomies use get_the_terms." Believe me...I wish I could use it....